# Is it possible to display different page layouts by using the responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-devices

I don't want to display some contents for example ads on the mobile devices.  Can I change  this  draft for the desktop

```
<DIV> ADS</DIV> <DIV> Content 1</DIV> 
<DIV> Content 2</DIV> <DIV> Content 3</DIV>
```

to something like the below one  for mobile layout ( without showing ads section )

```
<DIV> Content 1</DIV>
<DIV> Content 2</DIV>
<DIV> Content 3</DIV>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you give the ads a class, and use CSS `@media`:

```
<div class="Mobile-no-show">Ads</div>
<div>Everything Else...</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width:500px){
.Mobile-no-show{
display:none;
}
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5718fLu/)